# Can't retweet with tweepy - Python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

i'm trying to create a bot to retweet #dogs.
This is my code

```
    import tweepy

consumer_key = 'XXXXXXXXX'
consumer_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
access_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
access_token_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

user = api.me()
print(user.name)

def main():
    search = ('#dogs')
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items(1):
        try:
            tweet.retweet()
            print('Tweet Retweeted')
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            print(e.reason)
        except StopIteration:
            break

main()
```

When i run it, i get my username from (user.name) but it never sends the retweet.

CMD output:

```
C:\Users\xd\Desktop>python rt_bot.py
Dom
```

Answer (score 1):

`api.retweet(tweet)` instead of `tweet.retweet()` should probably do it.

For more reference: http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html?highlight=retweet

**EDIT:** From my comment - keep `tweet.retweet()` but remove the 1 from `tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items()`, so that you search through all tweets rather than just the first tweet you can.

The parameter of `items()` determines how many tweets you search through, and leaving it blank will allow you to search through as many as tweepy allows

Comment: Nope, i'm still getting the same output

Comment: My bad, keep `tweet.retweet()` but remove the 1 from `tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items()`, so that you search through all tweets rather than just the first tweet you can.